# Remove id attribute from Zend Form element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, zend-framework

I have:

```
$this->addElement('select', 'type', array(
        'label' => 'Banner type',
        'required' => true,
        'multiOptions' => array(
            ''   => 'Please select',
            '1'  => 'Image',
            '3'  => 'Flash',
            '4'  => 'Html'
        ),
        'value' => '',
));
```

but when rendered the selected `dropdown` it has the `id = "type"` attribute which I don't want. I am cloning this in JavaScript and after all the events it does not work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better modify your javascript (change id just when cloning element).

If you want to change the structure of your form element with ZF you have to create your own select element extending Zend_Form_Element_Select, then create your own formSelect view helper extending Zend_View_Helper_FormSelect and override the `formSelect()` method. Then see my comment below :

```
 $xhtml = '<select'
            . ' name="' . $this->view->escape($name) . '"'
            . ' id="' . $this->view->escape($id) . '"' // remove this line
            . $multiple
            . $disabled
            . $this->_htmlAttribs($attribs)
            . ">\n    ";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reset/change the id of an element once its cloned

(before you do anything with it i.e. inject back into the dom)

Simple crate a variable to hold the clone and changes it's `id` property. for example:

```
$(function (){
    var div = $('#myId');
    console.log(div[0].id); //shows the element id

    var newDiv = div.clone(); //clone the element
    console.log(newDiv[0].id); //shows original element id

    newDiv[0].id = "myNewId"; //change the id
    console.log(newDiv[0].id); //shows 'myNewId'
});
```

Comment: and what about php? when i want to do so via php?